# jquery chosen select plugin does not show drop down well when use overflow:hidden to outer div

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-chosen

I am trying to show drop down box to top of outer div but it outer div wraps drop down box?

Normal html select works well but chosen-select does not shows drop down well.....

Demo Fiddle : [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RGQGF/)

```
$(function(){
    $(".chosen-select").chosen();
})
```

html :

```
  <div style="height:150px;width:250px;overflow-y:auto;overflow-x:hidden;margin:20px;background: gray;">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <select  style="width: 200px; ">
                         <option value="0"></option>
                         <option value="1">One</option>
                         <option value="2">Two</option>
                         <option value="3">Three</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
           .
           .
       </tbody>
   </table>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

WOW after 5 years still didn't get the answer?

use this code and add width to your select box.

```
 $(".chosen-select").chosen({width: "95%"});
```

will solve your issue.

Answer (score -1):

This is because chosen renders your drop down into divs and sub divs. Make sure you set the overflow property of all parent containers to 'visible'.

The ordinary html select works here because of native html behavior

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```
    $('.chosen-select').on("chosen:showing_dropdown", function () {
            $(this).parents("div").css("overflow", "visible");
        });
```